Seeking a formula for $\sum\limits_{i=1,3,5,..}{n \choose 2i}$, where $n=4k$
Let $n=4k$  where $k=1,2,3,...$. I'm trying to get a formula for $$\sum\limits_{i=1,3,5,..}{n \choose 2i}$$
What I'm thinking is to use the known sum $$\sum\limits_{i=1,3,5,..}{n \choose 2i}+\sum\limits_{i=2,4,6,..}{n \choose 2i}=2^{n-1}-1$$ and then establish another equation for their difference so I can solve for what I want.
I did some calculations and found the following hold for $k=1,2,3,4$:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1,3,5,..}{n \choose 2i}-\sum\limits_{i=2,4,6,..}{n \choose 2i}=(-1)^{k+1}(2^{2k}+(-1)^{k+1}).$$
I have no clue how to prove this in general, or if it is a known result? Thanks.

What is the "known sum"?

Let $i^2=-1$. Note that
$$(1+i)^{n}=\sum_{j\equiv0\mod 4}\binom{n}{j}+i\sum_{j\equiv1\mod 4}\binom{n}{j}-\sum_{j\equiv2\mod 4}\binom{n}{j}-i\sum_{j\equiv3\mod 4}\binom{n}{j}$$
Considering the real part of the equality will give the equality you need.
